# Angular4 => Новый angular

Tags: angular, angular4, httpclient

Вообщем сижу изучаю angular4 и немного не могу догнать как переделать функцию выглядит она так:

```
getUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/users?email=${email}`).map((response: Response) => response.json()).map((user: User[]) => user[0] ? user [0] : undefined);
}
```

А сам запрос выглядит вот так:

```
const formData = this.form.value;
this.userService.getUserByEmail(formData.email).subscribe((user: User) => {
    console.log(user);
});
```

Я скачал последнюю версию Angular сейчас это 7.

Да кстати вот как выглядит бд, ясно что она в виде файла json:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "wfm@mail.ru",
            "password": "12345678",
            "name": "Администратор"
        }
    ]
}
```

Уже все перерыл, но как правильно этот запрос в библиотеке rxjs делается??

Comment: getUserByEmail(): Observable<User> {
        return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/users?email=${email}`).pipe(map(data=>{
            return data.users
        }));
    }

Comment: вопрос непонятен совсем `как правильно этот запрос в библиотеке rxjs делается??`, rxjs не делает запросы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular 7 использует rxjs выше 6 версий. Переделай у себя так

```
getUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<User> {
return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/users?email=${email}`).pipe(map((user: User[]) => user[0] ? user [0] : undefined));
```

}
И потом используй у себя HttpClient для него не нужно это делать

```
map((response: Response) => response.json())
```

он у тебя в конструктуре costructor(public http: HttpClient){} не забудь сделать импорт import {HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

Comment: Ну насчёт httpClient переживать не стоит я разрабатываются в phpStorm, поэтому всякие import  и прочие само подключается